# Добавить адекватный вывод для gtest

Tags: c++, gtest

Не могу найти информацию как добавить поддержку нормального вывода для типов, которые изначально не поддерживаются gtest

К примеру есть такой код

```
QList<QPair<QString, QString>> arr = {
    { eventService, "file1.exe" },
    { dummyTask, "file2.exe"},
};

for(auto &it : arr)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(WindowsNS::WinApiHelper::extractProcessName(it.first), it.second);
}
```

Если тест провалился, то вижу на экране примерно такой вывод

```
TestWindApiHelper.cpp(17): error: Expected equality of these values:
  WindowsNS::WinApiHelper::extractProcessName(it.first)
    Which is: { 2-byte object <54-00>, 2-byte object <53-00>, 2-byte object <44-00>, 2-byte object <75-00>, 2-byte object <6D-00>, 2-byte object <6D-00>, 2-byte object <79-00>, 2-byte object <41-00>, 2-byte object <70-00>, 2-byte object <70-00>, 2-byte object <2D-00>, 2-byte object <76-00>, 2-byte object <63-00>, 2-byte object <31-00>, 2-byte object <34-00>, 2-byte object <30-00>, 2-byte object <2D-00>, 2-byte object <73-00>, 2-byte object <2E-00>, 2-byte object <65-00>, 2-byte object <78-00>, 2-byte object <65-00> }
  it.second
    Which is: { 2-byte object <54-00>, 2-byte object <53-00>, 2-byte object <44-00>, 2-byte object <75-00>, 2-byte object <6D-00>, 2-byte object <6D-00>, 2-byte object <79-00>, 2-byte object <41-00>, 2-byte object <70-00>, 2-byte object <70-00>, 2-byte object <2D-00>, 2-byte object <76-00>, 2-byte object <63-00>, 2-byte object <31-00>, 2-byte object <34-00>, 2-byte object <30-00>, 2-byte object <2D-00>, 2-byte object <73-00>, 2-byte object <2E-00>, 2-byte object <65-00>, 2-byte object <78-00>, 2-byte object <65-00>, 2-byte object <31-00> }
```

Из этого списка байтов ничего не понятно, в чем проблема. Хотелось бы видеть текстовые значения. Предполагаю что нужно определить какой-то метод, где я укажу как эти данные правильно выводить на экран. Вот только какой?

Comment: готовый ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597726/how-to-pretty-print-qstring-with-googletest-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это функция у вас уже реализована, иначе вы бы получили ошибку компиляции.

Gtest поддерживает два варианта, оба требуют ADL:

перегруженный `operator <<`

```
::std::ostream &
operator <<(::std::ostream& os, Object const & object);
```

функция `PrintTo`:

```
void
PrintTo(Object const & object, ::std::ostream * os)
```

Comment: перегрузка PrintTo дала нужный результат. Перерузка operator<< почему то дает вывод вида ```Which is: { T, S, D, u, m, m, y, A, p, p, -, v, c, 1, 4, 0, -, s, ., e, x, e }```